# JDBC-ODBC SQLException:General Error

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am using JDK 1.6. With that I want to connect to an Access database. For that I've registered a System DNS & trying to connect that database using JDBC-ODBC connection.

When I connect it & test it by firing a simple query to check whether connection has been established properly or not.

Here is my code snippet to execute query.

```
public void testConnection() {
    Connection conn = DBUtil.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM inventory");

        System.out.println("Connection Successful");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }

            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling `testConnection()` method more than once.

Now the matter is that the query works fine for the first time, rest of three times it gives error, which is mentioned below.

```
java.sql.SQLException: General error
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.throwGenericSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:7086)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLAllocStmt(JdbcOdbc.java:173)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:465)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:443)
```

Please let me know where the thing goes wrong?

**Note**: I am running the program on Windows 7, 64 bit variant. Registered datasource using 32 bit driver on local machine (From path: `%windir%/SYSWOW64/odbcad32.exe`)

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure about this, but try something like this:

```
public void testConnection() {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pre =null;
    ResultSet rs =null;

    try {
        conn = DBUtil.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select id from inventory");
        rs = pre.executeQuery();

        System.out.println("Connection Successful");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
            conn.close(); 
    }
}
```